# ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2 on ARM

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I used to run an ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC1 project on my Raspberry Pi. Now I've converted the project to RC2 but there don't seem to be any ARM builds available of RC2.
Does anybody know the status of this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround.

**1. add the code in startup.cs like below.**

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorOptions(options =>
        {
            if (Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null)
            {
                var myAssemblyPaths = new[] {
             "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll",
             "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Core.dll",
             "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
             };
                var previous = options.CompilationCallback;
                options.CompilationCallback = (context) =>
                {
                    if (previous != null)
                    {
                        previous(context);
                    }

                    var references = myAssemblyPaths.Select(p => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(p)).ToArray();
                    context.Compilation = context.Compilation.AddReferences(references);
                };
            }
        });
```

**2. build on windows machine.**

**3. copy all the web project to linux target including output files.**

**4. run the app using mono.**

My web project name is AspNetCoreMonoTest.

"/root/AspNetCoreMonoTest" folder should have project.json.

Please execute by below command.

cd /root/AspNetCoreMonoTest && mono bin/Debug/net451/win7-x64/AspNetCoreMonoTest.exe

I used mono version 4.4.0. and refered to https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4818#issuecomment-224775503